# convert epoch to datetime format python - typeerror

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, typeerror, python-datetime

I have a dataframe with 2 columns - some values and Time. Timestamp is in epoch time format and I am trying to transform using the strftime function from time library in python.

Here's some sample data

```
df = [{'A': 762, 'Time': 1512255906},
      {'A': 810, 'Time': 1480719906}]
```

Note: time is in epoch format. I am performing some transformation to ensure it is of type **numeric(float)** before passing it through strftime function for date conversion.

Here's the code:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Time'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
df['Time'].dtype
```

I receive an error with when on this line

```
df['Time'] = time.strftime("%d-%m", time.localtime(df['Time']))
```

Traceback:

```
TypeError   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-86f4db0b80e4> in <module>()
 ----> 1 df['Time'] = time.strftime("%d-%m", time.localtime(df['Time']))

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

Comment: [you should consider accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I accepted them. thanks.

Comment: if you read the linked page carefully, it would explain that you can only accept one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import time

>>> df = pd.DataFrame([{'A': 762, 'Time': 1512255906},
                       {'A': 810, 'Time': 1480719906}])

>>> df['Time'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Time'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
>>> df['Time'] = df['Time'].apply(lambda t: time.strftime("%d-%m", time.localtime(t)))

>>> df
     A   Time
0  762  03-12
1  810  03-12
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a `unit` parameter for `pd.to_datetime` to know what unit of time the number is supposed to represent.  In this case, you start off with `Time` being seconds from epoch.  So we pass `'s'` as the `unit`.

```
df.assign(Time=pd.to_datetime(df.Time, unit='s').dt.strftime('%d-%m'))
# For in place, use:
# df.Time = pd.to_datetime(df.Time, unit='s').dt.strftime('%d-%m')

     A   Time
0  762  02-12
1  810  02-12
```